# Pull data using R from a specific weather station

Tags: r, rnoaa

I've looked through many pages of how to do this and they essentially all have the same R code suggestions, which I've followed. Here's the R code I'm using for the specific weather station I'm looking for:

```
library(rnoaa)
options(noaakey="MyKeyHere")
ncdc(datasetid='GHCND', stationid='GHCND:USW00014739', datatypeid='dly-tmax-normal', startdate='2017-05-15', enddate='2018-01-04')
```

The error message I get when I run this is:
Warning message:
Sorry, no data found

I've gone directly to the NOAA site (https://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/cdo-web/search) and manaually pulled the dataset out there (using the "daily summaries" dataset, which is the same as GHCND in the API). There is in fact data there for my entire date range.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/rnoaa/versions/0.8.4/topics/ncdc) says:

*Note that NOAA NCDC API calls can take a long time depending on the call. The NOAA API doesn't perform well with very long timespans, and will time out and make you angry - beware.*

Have you tried a smaller timespan?

Comment: I just went back and tried one day and it's still finding no data.

Comment: I actually just found a paper online and this process works where all the others did not. https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rnoaa/rnoaa.pdf